# Proving Ramanujan's formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

While reading [this PDF](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Berndt-Bhargava644-656.pdf), they introduced a theorem by Ramanujan:

---

> **Theorem**
>
> *If* $$\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2=3\lambda\gamma^2$$
>
> *Then*$$(\alpha+\lambda^2\gamma)^3+(\lambda\beta+\gamma)^3=(\lambda\alpha+\gamma)^3+(\beta+\lambda^2\gamma)^3$$

---

I was wondering if there is a simple way to prove this? You *could* just expand both sides and show that they are equivalent, but that doesn't give me insight to how Ramanujan came up with this formula in the first place.

**Note:** $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\lambda\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: You must add that the symbols represent natural numbers.

Comment: Even Ramanujan could often not explain how he came up with his results. The memoir by G.H.Hardy about him is fascinating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proof without expanding both sides.

Using that 
$$A^3-B^3=(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2)$$
we get
$$(\alpha+\lambda^2\gamma)^3-(\beta+\lambda^2\gamma)^3+(\lambda\beta+\gamma)^3-(\lambda\alpha+\gamma)^3$$

---

$$=(\alpha-\beta)((\alpha+\lambda^2\gamma)^2+(\alpha+\lambda^2\gamma)(\beta+\lambda^2\gamma)+(\beta+\lambda^2\gamma)^2)$$$$\qquad+(\lambda\beta-\lambda\alpha)((\lambda\beta+\gamma)^2+(\lambda\beta+\gamma)(\lambda\alpha+\gamma)+(\lambda\alpha+\gamma)^2)$$

---

$$=(\alpha-\beta)(\color{red}{\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2}+3\alpha\lambda^2\gamma+3\beta\lambda^2\gamma+3\lambda^4\gamma^2)$$$$\qquad+\lambda(\beta-\alpha)(\lambda^2(\color{red}{\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2})+3\lambda\beta\gamma+3\lambda\alpha\gamma+3\gamma^2)$$

---

$$=(\alpha-\beta)(\color{red}{3\lambda\gamma^2}+3\alpha\lambda^2\gamma+3\beta\lambda^2\gamma+3\lambda^4\gamma^2)$$$$\qquad+\lambda(\beta-\alpha)(\lambda^2\cdot \color{red}{3\lambda\gamma^2}+3\lambda\beta\gamma+3\lambda\alpha\gamma+3\gamma^2)$$

---

$$=(\alpha-\beta)(3\lambda\gamma^2+3\alpha\lambda^2\gamma+3\beta\lambda^2\gamma+3\lambda^4\gamma^2)$$$$\qquad-(\alpha-\beta)(3\lambda\gamma^2+3\alpha\lambda^2\gamma+3\beta\lambda^2\gamma+3\lambda^4\gamma^2)$$

$$\boxed{=0}$$

Comment: Okay, then why won't this work: If$$\beta^3+3\beta\lambda\gamma+\gamma^3=\lambda^3\tag1$$Then$$(\beta\epsilon-\gamma^2)^3+(\beta^2+\gamma\lambda)^3=(\beta\lambda+\gamma^2)^3+(\beta\epsilon-\gamma^2)^3$$